# R code for calculating ad stock / decay with carry over effect limit

Tags: r, time-series

Given a vector x say,

```
x <- c(10,0,0,20,0,0)
```

and ad stock of 0.8, how to calculate ad stock effect such that if the carry over effect is less than some limit k, say half of the original value, it will no longer be carried over.

Without that condition, I can simply use this:

```
filter(x, filter=0.8, method="recursive")
```

Which gives

```
10.0000  8.0000  6.4000 25.1200 20.0960 16.0768
```

But given that condition, if we apply adstock of 0.2 to 10 which gives,

```
10.0000  8.0000  6.4000  5.1200  4.096  3.2768  ...
```

the carry over effect should stop at 5.12 since 4.096 is less than half of 10. So the expected output would be:

```
10.0000  8.0000  6.4000 25.1200 16.0000 12.8000
```

Comment: Not sure if there is a function to do this, but I'd suggest to break your vector down into pieces then run `filter`?